# Maximise sum of pairwise distances in array

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization

Imagine a list `[e1, e2, ..., en]` and a function `f(e1, e2) -> number` that returns the distance between any two elements in constant time.

```
f(e, e) = 0
e1 != e2 => f(e1, e2) > 0
f(e1, e2) <= f(e1, e3) + f(e3, e2)
```

The goal is to permute the list so that the sum of pairwise distances of the elements is maximal.

I came up with a `O(n^2)` greedy algorithm that seems to be doing this:

1. Make a tabel of all pairwise distances (Or a triangular matrix)
2. Look for the largest distance, pick that pair as a starting point (Can be done in step 1)
3. Grow the list by adding the free element that increases the sum the most (maybe use a linked hash set to keep track of the elements picked so far and allow fast checking)

Please tell me if its incorrect. **Can you come up with/suggest a faster algorithm or substantial (non-complexity) speedups?** And what is the minimal complexity for solving this problem?

This problem is similar to finding the *longest path in a strictly positively weighted complete graph*, except for the fact that you know the characteristics of the distance function, it also bears some resemblance to the minimum spanning tree (Maybe there's more to this resemblance than I currently realise?).

(Probably this problem is equivalent to some known problem, I'd be interested to know which one)

Comment: This appears to be the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) in a metric space, which is NP-hard even for metrics with distance labels 1 and 2 only (use the Hamilton path problem as in the Wikipedia article).

Answer (score 1):

Your optimal permutation gives rise to a path where each node is connected to the next node in your permuted list. Thus you are looking for a longest simple path, which even for a metric space like you describe is NP-hard. (see wikipedia on longest path problem). Your greedy solution has the problem that if you choose two elements that are the farthest distance apart, then if there are two extra elements that are identical that project onto the midpoint of the line segment connecting the two original selected elements, then the optimal solution for these 4 points is actually to create a chain from the first endpoint to one of the center points to the other endpoint to the other center point, rather than connecting the farthest apart vertices originally (which would lead to then connecting to a center point, and then connecting to the other center point at distance 0, creating a shorter path by the triangle inequality).

Comment: I was afraid the greedy algorithm couldn't suffice, but I don't fully follow your example yet. Say you have points [(-2,0),(0,2),(0,2),(2,0)]. Then my algorithm forms these steps: l1 = [(-2,0)(0,2)], l2 = [l1(0,2)], l3 = [(0,2)l2], which seems to effectively be the longest path. Could you demonstrate an example when it doesn't work?