# Shuffle list to maximise distances between similar elements

Tags: shuffle

In a list of URLs

`http://a.com/foo
http://b.com/bar
http://a.com/monkey
http://c.com/prune
http://a.com/bear
http://b.com/walrus
http://b.com/baz
http://b.com/plugh`

I want to maximise the distance between any pair of `a.com`'s, any pair of `b.com`'s etc. This needs to be cheap but does not have to be optimum. (I am using a list of URLs to download files from websites `a.com`, `b.com`, `c.com`, and do not wish to visit any particular site with a higher frequency than necessary. In the example here, we would hit the `b.com` site 3 times in succession, which should be avoided.)

I would ideally like a Java library but would settle for pseudocode. 
[Maximise sum of pairwise distances in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071176/maximise-sum-of-pairwise-distances-in-array) seems to be a similar problem but didn't have a simple answer - I simply want something that's "good enough"

Comment: Sort by the digit?

Comment: @Internal the elements don't actually have digts - they are URLs distinguished by domain name only. And there may be many more a's than b's.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't obvious (to me). Perhaps you should give a small example of what the real data looks like.

Comment: Done. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no answers, I wrote my own. It's very crude but works. It reads a list of URLs, extracts the hosts, counts them and then fills a pigeon-hole array with indexes proportional to the inverse frequency of the hosts.

```
package org.xmlcml.cmine.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;

public class URLShuffler {

    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(URLShuffler.class);
    static {
        LOG.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    }
```

// in case we needed extra pigeonholes but it doesn't seem to for medium problems

```
    private static int TOL = 1;
    private List<String> urls;
    private Multiset<String> domains;
    private Map<String, Integer> currentIndexByDomain;
    private Map<String, Integer> countByDomain;
    private List<String> outputUrls;

    public URLShuffler() {

    }

    public void readURLs(List<String> urls) {
        this.urls= urls;
        domains = HashMultiset.create();
        for (String url : urls) {
            String domain = getDomain(url);
            domains.add(domain);
        }
        LOG.debug(domains);
    }

// this would be better using java.net.URL

    private String getDomain(String url) {
        int idx = url.indexOf("//");
        if (idx != -1) {
            url = url.substring(idx+2);
        }
        idx = url.indexOf("/");
        String domain = url.substring(0,  idx);
        return domain;
    }

    public List<String> getShuffledUrls() {
        currentIndexByDomain = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        countByDomain = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        outputUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.size() * TOL; i++) {
            outputUrls.add("");
        }
```

// this is a convenience method wrapping Guava sort.

```
        for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry : CMineUtil.getEntriesSortedByCount(domains)) {
            LOG.debug(entry);
            countByDomain.put(entry.getElement(), entry.getCount());
            currentIndexByDomain.put(entry.getElement(), entry.getCount() - 1);
        }
        for (String url : urls) {
            String domain = getDomain(url);
            Integer currentIndex = currentIndexByDomain.get(domain);
            Integer count = countByDomain.get(domain);
            int slot = (urls.size() * currentIndex * TOL) / count;
            currentIndexByDomain.put(domain, currentIndex - 1);
            addUrl(url, slot);
        }
        return outputUrls;
    }

    private void addUrl(String url, int slot) {
        boolean filled = fillLower(url, slot);
        if (!filled) {
            fillUpper(url, slot);
        }
    }

// if slot is not free run upwards till next free slot

    private boolean fillUpper(String url, int slot) {
        for (int i = slot; i < outputUrls.size(); i++) {
            if (fill(url, i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

// if slot is not free run downwards till next free slot
    private boolean fillLower(String url, int slot) {
        for (int i = slot; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (fill(url, i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean fill(String url, int slot) {
        if (outputUrls.get(slot).equals("")) {
            outputUrls.set(slot, url);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```